# I would like to autoupdate a listbox value in a cel whitout using a button

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, auto-update

Good morning everyone,

I wrote a code to put the listbox values in a cell in Excel by pushing a button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

myVar = ""

For X = 0 To Me.transportation.ListCount - 1
    If Me.transportation.Selected(X) Then
        If myVar = "" Then
            myVar = Me.transportation.List(X, 0)
        Else
            myVar = myVar & "," & Me.transportation.List(X, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next X

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Visit 1").Range("d49") = myVar
Me.Hide

End Sub
```

I would like to change it that it auto updates without using a button

Comment: Is it an ActiveX ListBox or a FormControl ListBox?

Comment: I am sorry but I am new so not sure, it is created with the listbox option from the toolbox

Comment: Yes, but there are 2 different ListBoxes there: `ActiveX` and `FormControl`. You need to know which one it is, because the answer depends on the type of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends if it is an ActiveX ListBox or a FormControl ListBox.

- **ActiveX**
  Use the `ListBox1_Change` to run your code (where `ListBox1` is the name of your ListBox).
- **FormControl**
  Right click onto your ListBox and assign your macro to the ListBox.

  [image]

---

*If you are able to choose the type of your ListBox, I recommend to stay away from ActiveX and use the FormControl instead. ActiveX is known to cause issues sometimes.*

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I cannot find it but think that it is an active x one, can you please change my code in the correct one because can't still can't get it work

Comment: See my added image. ① Select your ListBox (name may be different) ② Select the `Change` event ③ Add your code to the created `_Change` event.

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned a lot from your comments, very clear.